# Gitlab-CI image and services

Tags: gitlab-ci

Within the yml file of the gitlab-ci pipeline there are image and services. How are they related? Can I build a docker image that can provide more for a gitlab stage via services? Does anyone of you have a dockerfile which can be integrated as an image and as services?

```
build_stage:
  image: my_docker_image
  services: 
    - service_from_docker_image
```

"The services keyword defines just another Docker image that is run during
your job and is linked to the Docker image that the image keyword defines.
This allows you to access the service image during build time."

The explanation on the gitlab page doesn't make that very clear to me yet.

Comment: Didn't this paragraph help?? [What services are not for](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-services-are-not-for)

Comment: sorry I didnt see this part of the documentation. Do you know how these network services can be located by gitlab-ci?